# include a html page, and discard css style after page has rendered

Tags: php, html, css, iframe, include

How can I include a file, but 'forget' everything about it after it has been included and rendered; contain it, so to speak.

Back in the day, I guess I would have just used a frame but now times have changed. I suppose an iframe is still fair game.... but are there any other ways?

p.s. *I can't edit the included file :).*

**index.php**

```
<?php
echo '<p>This is some left-aligned text</p>';
include 'include.html';
echo '<p>This is some more left-aligned text</p>';
?>
```

**include.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is some centered text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

```
                       This is some left-aligned text

                       This is some centered text

                       This is some more left-aligned text
```

**Desired Output**

```
This is some left-aligned text

                       This is some centered text

This is some more left-aligned text
```

**'Ultimate' Objective**
Just to give some more information, I have an epub file. I load the container.xml to determine the root file which is a .opf file which tells me the spint, which contains lots of .html file...

I am then including all of these html files into the page so that an epub can be read in one continuous flow.

The epub files cannot be edited? Unless I can do this without modifying the epub files permanently.

Comment: Are you just trying to append some html to the page from another file?

Comment: I don't think I understood actually 'why' you would want to disable a css style after you rendered it. If you disable it, the page is rendered again as if the style that you disabled was not there.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the CSS. I want to 'contain' my included file so that whatever it does does not affect the rest of my site.

Comment: Use inline styling, or use an ID on your container element of the included file that is unique.

Comment: In the example with index.php and include.html I get the output where everything is centered because the included html page has a style which centers everything in the body. However I am hoping to 'forget' this and anything else include.html came with so the rest of my content, which is within index.php is not altered.

Comment: @Emdiesse Just a little syntax sidenote:  Assuming index.php has it's own html, head, and body tags, you should not include the html, head, and body tags of an included file.

Comment: Unless you start styling with `p {some_styles...}`, your included file(s) won't be affected. Use CSS to your advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the file as a string and load only the body of the html file, becouse you can't have 2 HTML tags in the same file.

```
<?php
echo '<p class=\'left\'>This is some left-aligned text</p>';
$html = file_get_contents('include.html');
preg_match('/\<body\>(.*?)\<\/body\>/is', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
echo '<p class=\'left\'>This is some more left-aligned text</p>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this has helped. I modified the regular expression slightly so it is /\<body.*?\>(.*?)\<\/body\>/is which took into account any attributes the body tag may have. However, this increased load time quite considerable of some of my epubs.

Comment: Hi, I have a directory structure as follows
/index.php
/Articles/0/file1.html
to
/Articles/0/file20.html

In total, there is about 500kB wort of HTML files my index is rendering. I am turning them all into one flat html file on the fly for the user...

I may have to rethink my approach and perhaps focus on having 1 html file precompiled for webviewing so the server doesn't have to do it each time.

Comment: I've accepted this one as my answer, although truely all answers together have helped. This one has helped me to understand the manipulation I am going to HAVE to do to render everything on a single page. I have also just through that DOMDocument is probably also something I should look into for manipulating the html without regex. Upon another run, the regex was quicker, however maybe using DOMDoc would help me in manipulating everything correctly so I can make sure styles imported by an individual file are only applied to that files body, which I guess I could accomplish by adding a wrapper

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use scoped css, but is an experimental feature.
So in the head of **index.php** you should include this jquery plugin: https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin

then, to achieve what you want to achieve, you have to change your **include.html** file to the following:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style scoped>
body{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
<p>This is some centered text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this should do the trick and make you load 'every' include page you want to include without letting its style to influence the rest of the document.. but in the limits of the JQuery plugin you are using (it has some problems).
Chrome and Firefox currently implement this specific feature natively and don't need this plugin.

Comment: I will look into this for the future, when it's a little less experimental :). In the mean time I am going to just suffice with iframes.

Comment: If you want to know "how much" experimental is, you have to know that Firefox implemented it in the last release (that came live some days ago) and Chrome uses it within its "Experimental Webkit features". The JQuery plugin works pretty well, though it has some problems handling styles with @import rules.

Answer (score 1):

Just create css classes on index.php

```
<?php
echo '<p class=\'left\'>This is some left-aligned text</p>';
include 'include.html';
echo '<p class=\'left\'>This is some more left-aligned text</p>';
?>
```

In the style tag add on index.php:

```
<style type="text/css">
.left{text-align:left;}
</style>
```

No changes needed to your "included" html file.

And it should now work fine with that include. I will say that an iframe is perfectly fine, depending on what you are doing. The current demo page you have doesn't make a lot of sense, but I assume this is just for testing. So the above should work fine for you.

Comment: I like this idea, it definitely works for this one file include. I didn't explain the rest of my issue until now, but this would not solve the issue where a second included file will still be affected. Thanks.